# Rails - Display / Manage many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, relationship

I'm a beginner in the wonderful Rails world, but I find some difficulties.

Here's my situation :

I have some Users, Users using Webapps, and appears a join table, "Quota", to track activities of each user on each webapp.

So, in the database table of Quota we find : user_id, webapp_id, quantity : int.

My models :

```
class Webapp < ActiveRecord::Base
  #has_many :webapps_quota, :through => :quota, source: :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :quota
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quota
end

class Webapp < ActiveRecord::Base
  #has_many :webapps_quota, :through => :quota, source: :webapp 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :quota
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quota
end

class Quota < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :webapp
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :webapp
end
```

I'm seriously desperate about how I deal with this. How do I show his quota to an user for example?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add attributes in the association table you should use `has_many through` association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quotas
  has_many :webapps, through: :quotas
end

class Quota < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :webapp
end

class Webapp < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quotas
  has_many :users, through: :quotas
end
```

Your question: `How do I show his quota to an user for example?`

```
user = User.find(1)
user.quotas  #display the quotas for that user
user.webapps #display the webapps for that user
```

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm! (I also find the same informations as yours here : http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many )

But, can you give me more informations about how to have in the view something like 'user.webapp' = 'associate quota' ? 

It's ok to display each quota of the users using the each function, but I don't get how to match both.

Thanks again!

Comment: `user.webapps` will list all the webapps for that user. So, if you loop through it (`user.webapps.each do |webapp|` and inside the loop you call `webapp.quotas`) you can get all the quotas for each webapp related to this specific user.